# Get the class of the element that triggered the mouseover event jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the class value of the element that triggered my mouseover event in jquery?I have this code:

```
 <script>
 $(".img-thumb").on("mouseover", function () {
 $val = $(this).data("class");
 alert($val);
 });
 </script>
```

Sorry I'm a complete newbie here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(".img-thumb").on("mouseover", function (e) {
   alert($(e.currentTarget).attr('class'))
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/r0rt3ym4/1/)

Comment: I tried this  $(".img-thumb").on("mouseover", function (e) {
   console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr('class'))
   $val = e.currentTarget).attr('class');
   alert($val);
 }); its not working

Comment: $val = e.currentTarget).attr('class'); alert($val); }); is wrong

Comment: $val = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class'); alert($val);

Comment: Ill accept ur answer in a bit. just accepted a while ago

Comment: Glad my answer helped :)